# NullPointerException - Can't seem to where it is at

Tags: java, android

**Logcat**

```
07-07 16:03:11.203: E/AndroidRuntime(18538): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-07 16:03:11.203: E/AndroidRuntime(18538): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tp.mp2014.dotmatrix/tp.mp2014.dotmatrix.bluetoothtest}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    07-07 16:03:11.203: E/AndroidRuntime(18538):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2129)
    07-07 16:03:11.203: E/AndroidRuntime(18538):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2154)
    07-07 16:03:11.203: E/AndroidRuntime(18538):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:146)
    07-07 16:03:11.203: E/AndroidRuntime(18538):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1260)
    07-07 16:03:11.203: E/AndroidRuntime(18538):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    07-07 16:03:11.203: E/AndroidRuntime(18538):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    07-07 16:03:11.203: E/AndroidRuntime(18538):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4949)
    07-07 16:03:11.203: E/AndroidRuntime(18538):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-07 16:03:11.203: E/AndroidRuntime(18538):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    07-07 16:03:11.203: E/AndroidRuntime(18538):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1043)
    07-07 16:03:11.203: E/AndroidRuntime(18538):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
    07-07 16:03:11.203: E/AndroidRuntime(18538):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-07 16:03:11.203: E/AndroidRuntime(18538): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    07-07 16:03:11.203: E/AndroidRuntime(18538):    at tp.mp2014.dotmatrix.bluetoothtest.onCreate(bluetoothtest.java:114)
    07-07 16:03:11.203: E/AndroidRuntime(18538):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5185)
    07-07 16:03:11.203: E/AndroidRuntime(18538):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
    07-07 16:03:11.203: E/AndroidRuntime(18538):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2093)
    07-07 16:03:11.203: E/AndroidRuntime(18538):    ... 11 more
```

**bluetoothtest.java**

```
package tp.mp2014.dotmatrix;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;


import tp.mp2014.dotmatrix.ChatListAdapter;
import tp.mp2014.dotmatrix.ChatListAdapter.SiriListItem;
import tp.mp2014.dotmatrix.deviceListAdapter;
import tp.mp2014.dotmatrix.deviceListAdapter.deviceListItem;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothClass;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class bluetoothtest extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private ArrayList<deviceListItem> list;
    private ArrayList<SiriListItem> delist;
    private ButtonClicked clicked;
    private readThread mreadThread = null;
    private String BlueToothAddress;

    final byte ANIMATION_MODE=1;
    final byte PICTURE_MODE=2;
    final byte TEXT_MODE=3;
    int count = 0, click = 0;

    ListView listViewPaired;
    ListView deviceList;
    ListView chatList;

    deviceListAdapter mAdapter;
    ChatListAdapter chAdapter;
    Context mContext;

    TextView btStatus;
    ArrayList<String> arrayListpaired;
    Button buttonSearch,buttonOn,buttonDesc,buttonOff, buttonConnect;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    static HandleSeacrh handleSeacrh;
    BluetoothSocket socket;
    BluetoothDevice bdDevice;
    BluetoothClass bdClass;
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices;


    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = null;
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> arrayListBluetoothDevices = null;



    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        list = new ArrayList<deviceListAdapter.deviceListItem>();
        delist = new ArrayList<ChatListAdapter.SiriListItem>();
        chAdapter = new ChatListAdapter(this, delist);
        mAdapter = new deviceListAdapter(this, list);

        deviceList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.deviceList);
        buttonSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSearch);
        buttonOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOn);
        buttonDesc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDesc);
        buttonOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOff); 
        buttonConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connectBtn);
        btStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btStatus);
        //arrayListpaired = new ArrayList<String>();
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        clicked = new ButtonClicked();
        handleSeacrh = new HandleSeacrh();
        //arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        deviceList.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);
        /*
         * the above declaration is just for getting the paired bluetooth devices;
         * this helps in the removing the bond between paired devices.
         */


        deviceList.setAdapter(chAdapter);
        chatList.setAdapter(mAdapter);




        buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (count == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(bluetoothtest.this,
                            "Please connect to the bluetooth first or check the bluetooth open or not ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } 
                // Need API=14
                else if (!socket.isConnected()) {
                        Toast.makeText(bluetoothtest.this,
                                "Please waiting for connecting !!!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                else {
                    try {
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        buttonOn.setOnClickListener(clicked);
        buttonSearch.setOnClickListener(clicked);
        buttonDesc.setOnClickListener(clicked);
        buttonOff.setOnClickListener(clicked);

    }




    private void getPairedDevices() {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();            
        if(pairedDevice.size()>0)
        {
            for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevice)
            {
                arrayListpaired.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress());
                arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices.add(device);

            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    /*private void callThread() {
        new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                Boolean isBonded = false;
                try {
                    isBonded = createBond(bdDevice);
                    if(isBonded)
                    {
                        arrayListpaired.add(bdDevice.getName()+"\n"+bdDevice.getAddress());
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                }//connect(bdDevice);
                Log.i("Log", "The bond is created: "+isBonded);
            }           
        }.start();
    }*/

    private Boolean connect(BluetoothDevice bdDevice) { 
        Boolean bool = false;
        try {
            Log.i("Log", "service method is called ");
            Class cl = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
            Class[] par = {};
            Method method = cl.getMethod("createBond", par);
            Object[] args = {};
            bool = (Boolean) method.invoke(bdDevice);//, args);// this invoke creates the detected devices paired.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Log", "Inside catch of serviceFromDevice Method");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bool.booleanValue();
    };


    public boolean removeBond(BluetoothDevice btDevice)  
    throws Exception  
    {  
        Class btClass = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
        Method removeBondMethod = btClass.getMethod("removeBond");  
        Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) removeBondMethod.invoke(btDevice);  
        return returnValue.booleanValue();  
    }


    public boolean createBond(BluetoothDevice btDevice)  
    throws Exception  
    { 
        Class class1 = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
        Method createBondMethod = class1.getMethod("createBond");  
        Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) createBondMethod.invoke(btDevice);  
        return returnValue.booleanValue();  
    }  


    class ButtonClicked implements OnClickListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonOn:
                onBluetooth();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonSearch:
                arrayListBluetoothDevices.clear();
                startSearching();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonDesc:
                makeDiscoverable();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonOff:
                offBluetooth();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                Toast.makeText(context, "ACTION_FOUND", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    delist.add(new SiriListItem(device.getName() + "\n"
                            + device.getAddress(), false));
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    deviceList.setSelection(delist.size() - 1);
                }
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED
                    .equals(action)) {
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                if (deviceList.getCount() == 0) {
                    delist.add(new SiriListItem(
                            "Did not find a bluetooth device", false));
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    deviceList.setSelection(list.size() - 1);
                }
                }
            }           
        };

    private void startSearching() {
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Toast.makeText(bluetoothtest.this,
                    "Please open the bluetooth first",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            buttonSearch.setText("Search bluetooth devices");
        } else if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                buttonSearch.setText("Search again");
            } else {
                delist.clear();
                chAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
                if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                    for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                        delist.add(new SiriListItem(device.getName()
                                + "\n" + device.getAddress(), true));
                        chAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        deviceList.setSelection(delist.size() - 1);
                    }
                } else {
                    delist.add(new SiriListItem(
                            "No devices have been paired", true));
                    delist.clear();
                    chAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    deviceList.setSelection(delist.size() - 1);
                }
                /* start discovery */
                bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }
        }
    };
    private void onBluetooth() {
        String text = "Bluetooth Status: Turned on";
        btStatus.setText(text);
        btStatus.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        if(!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
            bluetoothAdapter.enable();
            Log.i("Log", "Bluetooth is Enabled");

        }
    }
    private void offBluetooth() {
        String text = "Bluetooth Status: Turned off";

        if(bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
            bluetoothAdapter.disable();
            btStatus.setText(text);
            btStatus.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }
    private void makeDiscoverable() {
        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);
        Log.i("Log", "Discoverable ");
    }
    class HandleSeacrh extends Handler
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case 111:

                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    SharedPreferences sp;
private void sendMessageHandle(String msg) {

        final byte ANIMATION_MODE=1;
        final byte PICTURE_MODE=2;
        final byte TEXT_MODE=3;
        final String PAUSE = "\r";

        int temp,row;

        sp = getSharedPreferences("SaveData",MODE_PRIVATE);

        byte mode = (byte) sp.getInt("Mode",1);
        byte [] pictureData = new byte [129];
        byte [] textSetting =new byte [5];

        if (socket == null) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "No connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            return;
        }
        try {
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            if(mode==TEXT_MODE){
                textSetting[0]='T';
                textSetting[1]=(byte) sp.getInt("directionData", '1');
                textSetting[2]=(byte) sp.getInt("positionData", '1');
                textSetting[3]=(byte) sp.getInt("speedSeekBar", 10);
                if(sp.getBoolean("checkBox1", true)){
                    textSetting[4]=1 ;                          
                }
                else
                    textSetting[4]=0 ;

                os.write(textSetting);  
                os.write(msg.getBytes());
            }
            else if(mode==PICTURE_MODE){
                pictureData[0]='B';
                for(int col=0;col<32;col++){
                    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){   //! each byte

                        temp=(col<<2)+i+1;
                        for(int j=7;j>=0;j--){  //within 1 byte LSB last
                            row=(i<<3)+j;
                            pictureData[temp]<<=1;
                            if(sp.getBoolean("ledData"+(col+10)+(row+10), false)==true){        //
                                pictureData[temp]++;
                            }
                        }//for each byte
                        System.out.println("Byte info:col "+col +" row(/8) "+i +" "+pictureData[temp]);
                    }//col
                }//for row  
                os.write(pictureData);  
            }
            else if(mode==ANIMATION_MODE){
                textSetting[0]='A';
                textSetting[1]=(byte) sp.getInt("animationIndex", 1);
                textSetting[2]='\r';
                os.write(textSetting);
            }
            System.out.println("Mode: "+mode);
                                                    //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            os.write(PAUSE.getBytes());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        list.add(new deviceListItem(msg, false));
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        chatList.setSelection(list.size() - 1);
    }

    private class clientThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {

            try {
                //
                bdDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(BlueToothAddress);
                socket = bdDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID
                        .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
                Message msg2 = new Message();
                msg2.obj = "Please wait, connecting to the server:"
                        + BlueToothAddress;
                msg2.what = 0;
                LinkDetectedHandler.sendMessage(msg2);
                socket.connect();

                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.obj = "Connected !!! Can send message.";
                msg.what = 0;
                LinkDetectedHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                mreadThread = new readThread();
                mreadThread.start();
                click++;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.obj = "Exception! Disconnect to try it again";
                msg.what = 0;
                LinkDetectedHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                click--;
                //sendedtTxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                // Enable the openBtn,closeBtn£¬discoverBtn
                //discoverBtn.setClickable(true);
            }
        }
    };

    private Handler LinkDetectedHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (String) msg.obj,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (msg.what == 1) {
                list.add(new deviceListItem((String) msg.obj, true));
            } else {
                list.add(new deviceListItem((String) msg.obj, false));
            }
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            chatList.setSelection(list.size() - 1);
        }

    };


    private class readThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;
            InputStream mmInStream = null;
            String tmp = null;
            try {
                mmInStream = socket.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // read the data from the inputStream 
                    if ((bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer)) > 0) 
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
                            tmp = "" + buffer[i];
                            String st = new String(tmp);
                            tmp = null;
                            Message msg = new Message();
                            msg.obj = st;
                            msg.what = 1;

                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    try {
                        mmInStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // Cancel discovery because it's costly and we're about to connect

                        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                        if(delist.size() == 0)
                        {
                            Log.i("Tag", "Size is = "+delist.size());
                        }
                        SiriListItem item = delist.get(arg2);
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        // When device being clicked
                        count++;
                        click = 1;
                        //sendedtTxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
                        // Disable the open bluetooth button,the close bluetooth button,the
                        // open bluetooth button
                        //openBtn.setClickable(false);
                        //discoverBtn.setClickable(false);

                        // Get the device MAC address, which is the last 17 chars in the
                        // View
                        String info = item.message;
                        String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);
                        BlueToothAddress = address;
                //      String name = info.substring()
                        if (click == 1) {
                            clientThread ct = new clientThread();
                            ct.start();

        }
};
};


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }



}
```

Been getting the **NullPointerException** but I can't seem to find the where the problems lies. I've tried to remove any possible array related stuff but still didn't work. Anyone kind enough to help me out?

Comment: Which line is line 114?

Comment: @Jens -    `chatList.setAdapter(mAdapter);`

Comment: It's exactly what the logcat says, NullPointerException at Line 114. Your ListView is null.

Comment: @Marius - Oh god. How dumb am I . Sorry guys for the trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't initialized your chatList so `chatList.setAdapter(mAdapter);` is giving Null Pointer Exception.

```
 ListView chatList;
 chatList.setAdapter(mAdapter); //NullPointerException
```

So do,

```
 ListView chatList;
 chatList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chatList);
 chatList.setAdapter(mAdapter); //Now OK
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you haven't initialised chatList